# Why does 'await' not do anything in NextJS API Routing?

Tags: api, routes, next.js, async-await

I'm trying to fetch data from the YouTube Data API from a NextJS Api Route (this is meant to be a cron function).

I used the await keyword when getting data (the getPlaylistData() function), but I always get the error that res is undefined. The api call goes through without the console.log(res.status) and returns status 200, so I know the API call is good.

Additionally I get the proper output in the console.log() functions in the callback of service.playlistItems.list. The console.log(res.status) seems to run before the getPlaylistData() function finishes.

Am I misunderstanding the way async/await works? Any advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Some other information that might help:
OS: Windows 11
Framework: NextJS 13 (Beta) with app directory enabled
IDE: WebStorm
I am using Postman to test the api route call.

## Code

```
const {google} = require('googleapis')

const service = google.youtube('v3');
export async function GET() {
    const res = await getPlaylistData()
    // console.log(res.status);
    return new Response("Success", {
        status:200
    })
}

async function getPlaylistData() {
    const dataRes = await service.playlistItems.list({
        auth: process.env.API_KEY,
        part: "snippet,contentDetails,status",
        playlistId: process.env.UPLOADS_ID,
    }, function(err:any, res:any) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
            return;
        }
        let playlistItems = res.data.items;
        if (playlistItems.length == 0) {
            console.log("No playlistItems found");
        } else {
            console.log('This channel\'s latest video is: ' + playlistItems[0].snippet.title)
            console.log(typeof(playlistItems))
        }
    })
    return dataRes;
}
```

Comment: You are not returning anything inside `getPlaylistData`. That is if `playlistItems.list` works with promises. Otherwise, just return your response from the callback.

Comment: I tried this, but the `console.log(res.status)` still runs before the `getPlaylistData` function is finished. The output for the functions shows res = undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a Promise from the getPlaylistData function worked.

```
async function getPlaylistData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        service.playlistItems.list({
            auth: process.env.API_KEY,
            part: "snippet,contentDetails,status",
            playlistId: process.env.UPLOADS_ID,
        }, async function(err:any, res:any) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
                return;
            }
            let playlistItems = res.data.items;
            if (playlistItems.length == 0) {
                console.log("No playlistItems found");
            } else {
                console.log('This channel\'s latest video is: ' + playlistItems[0].snippet.title)
                // console.log(playlistItems)
            }
            console.log(typeof(res))
            resolve(res)
        })
    })
}
```